# access performance monitor object

Tags: performance, vbscript, performancecounter, perfmon

I have in my machine a performance object that it not a default but one of the dev here create it .

this performance object collect some information of one of our process.( not the regular counter such as memory usage but our custom counter ).

I want to access to this data by vb script .

I know how to do it for regular object such as process :

```
Set objInstance1 = objCimv2.Get( _
        "Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor.Name='_Total'")
```

but I don't know how to do it for custom performance object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom performance counters are created following the same convention as other performance counters:

Win32_*PerfRawData or PerfFormattedData*_CategoryName_CounterName.

Grab the [WMI Explorer](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/WMI-Explorer.shtml), it gives you a dump of all the WMI classes on your machine and their properties.  Your custom counters will appear in that list.

Hope this helps!